# What is the proper way to define attributes in a PyCXX extension

Tags: python, c++, pycxx

I wonder what the proper way is to define attributes in a python extension generated with PyCxx.
Currently I have created a subclass of `Py::PythonClass` as in the official [example](http://sourceforge.net/p/cxx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CXX/Demo/Python2/simple.cxx).
I've added `behaviors().supportGetattro();` in the initialization function and created a simple override of

```
Py::Object getattro( const Py::String &name_ )
{
    std::string name( name_.as_std_string( "utf-8" ) );

    if( name == "name" )
    {
        return m_name;
    }
    else
    {
        return genericGetAttro( name_ );
    }
}
```

So far so good. In python I get the proper value with `obj.name`, but the only thing that makes me unsatified is that when calling `dir(obj)` the `name` attribute does not get listed. How can I change that?

Comment: Maybe the question should be how to declare attributes in PyCXX. Accessing the attribute works with the code above, but I want it to be also listed when printing the attributes and methods of the object, like it's the case when defining `tp_getset` when not using PyCXX.

Comment: Ok I'm adding the attribute declarations now by using `PyGetSetDef()`. The only obstacle is then to get acces to the `tp_getset` variable (protected) but I'm defining a subclass of `PythonType` as helper now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barry Scott, developer of PyCXX kindly provided a simple solution.
The trick is that python asks for the value of `__members__` in `getattr( const char *_name )` when calling `dir()`. In this case one can return a `Py::List` object containing the attribute names as strings.

Comment: It seems it is not working for Python 3. Do you have a solution for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3 `dir` is using the `__dict__` member in `getattr( const char *_name )` (among other things). It is expected to be a `Py:Dict` linking the attribute names to their values.

The `dir` function keeps only the attribute name for it return value.

Here is the code of `dir()` to source the answer.

```c
static PyObject *
object_dir(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    PyObject *dict = NULL;
    PyObject *itsclass = NULL;

    /* Get __dict__ (which may or may not be a real dict...) */
    dict = _PyObject_GetAttrId(self, &PyId___dict__);
    if (dict == NULL) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        dict = PyDict_New();
    }
    else if (!PyDict_Check(dict)) {
        Py_DECREF(dict);
        dict = PyDict_New();
    }
    else {
        /* Copy __dict__ to avoid mutating it. */
        PyObject *temp = PyDict_Copy(dict);
        Py_DECREF(dict);
        dict = temp;
    }

    if (dict == NULL)
        goto error;

    /* Merge in attrs reachable from its class. */
    itsclass = _PyObject_GetAttrId(self, &PyId___class__);
    if (itsclass == NULL)
        /* XXX(tomer): Perhaps fall back to obj->ob_type if no
                       __class__ exists? */
        PyErr_Clear();
    else if (merge_class_dict(dict, itsclass) != 0)
        goto error;

    result = PyDict_Keys(dict);
    /* fall through */
error:
    Py_XDECREF(itsclass);
    Py_XDECREF(dict);
    return result;
}
```